# How can I tell NERDTree to open a file in the current window, even if its open somewhere else?

Tags: vim-windows, tabbed-user-interface, plugin-nerdtree

If I have file `foo.txt` open in a tab

```
 tab1
+------------+------------+
|            |            |
|            |            |
|  file:     | file:      |
|  foo.txt   | bar.txt    |
|            |            |
|            |            |
+------------+------------+
```

then I open another tab using `tabe .` the  NERDTree explorer launches, something like:

```
tab1                               tab 2
+------------+------------+     +-------------------------+
|            |            |     |                         |
|            |            |     | ▸ resources-desktop/    |
|  file:     | file:      |     | ▸ resources-shared/     |
|  foo.txt   | bar.txt    |     | ▸ server_v2/            |
|            |            |     |   .gitignore            |
|            |            |     |   foo.txt               |
+------------+------------+     |   bar.txt               |
                                +-------------------------+
```

Then using NERDTree in tab2 I navigate to  `foo.txt` and select with <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

What I want to happen is this

```
tab1                               tab 2
+------------+------------+     +-------------------------+
|            |            |     |                         |
|            |            |     |                         |
|  file:     | file:      |     |                         |
|  foo.txt   | bar.txt    |     |                         |
|            |            |     |                         |
|            |            |     |   foo.txt               |
+------------+------------+     |                         |
                                +-------------------------+
```

What I am getting is no change focus just jumps back to first `foo.txt`

```
tab1                               tab 2
+------------+------------+     +-------------------------+
|            |            |     |                         |
|            |            |     | ▸ resources-desktop/    |
|  file:     | file:      |     | ▸ resources-shared/     |
|  foo.txt   | bar.txt    |     | ▸ server_v2/            |
|            |            |     |   .gitignore            |
|            |            |     |   foo.txt               |
+------------+------------+     |   bar.txt               |
  ^^^^^                         +-------------------------+
  Focus just 
  goes back here
```

Is it possible to open `foo.txt` in the 2nd tab/window with NERDTree?

Comment: I don't know if it will help but I found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30022579

Comment: thanks, I saw that and tried it too. it didnt seem to do anything